# 415- Unsupported Media Type Error | angularjs + Spring3.2

Tags: angularjs, web-services, spring-mvc, http-post, http-status-code-415

I am getting 415 error in browser. I am not able to find the mistake. Could you please help.

- loginController.js

$scope.user = {email: "admin", password: "password"};

```
$http.post('/expense-manager-api/login/authenticate', $scope.user, {
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
}).success(function(login) {
    $scope.setError(login.status);
    $location.path("main");
}).error(function() {
    $scope.setError('Invalid user/password combination');
});
```

- LoginController.java

@Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/login")

public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public
@ResponseBody
LoginResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
    if (loginRequest.getEmail().equals("admin") && loginRequest.getPassword().equals("password")) {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

        return new LoginResponse(uuid.toString(), "OK");
    }

    return new LoginResponse(null, "Invalid user/password combination");
}
```

}

[image: Network Call]

[image: request and response headers]

Comment: Can you post what the HTTP request looks like on Firebug or Chrome Dev console?

Comment: @geoand I added the photos.

Comment: It seems that Spring is returning `text/html`. Are you sure that there aren't any errors in the logs?

Comment: Yes. There are no errors in the logs.

Comment: If I debug the server side code. It is not even coming to the first line of the method. And my response body is "LoginRespone" which is object. How can it be text/html?

Comment: Have you deployed your application under `expense-manager-api`? Spring is returning `text/html` as a default error page

Comment: So, how and where to specify the return contentType?

Comment: The problem is not the return content type. The problem is that Spring has not found a mapping for your request. Are you sure `localhost:8080/expense-manager-api/login/authenticate` is a valid URL for your application?

Comment: Yes. I am sure that url is fine. otherwise it would have thrown 404.

Comment: Do i need to specify something in any .xml?

Comment: I found the issue. It was mapping issue which is resolved by jackson-mapper. But now i am getting bad request 400. Do you have any idea why it is throwing 400? and Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You should update your question with the new data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson mapper fixed the problem.

add maven dependency of Jackson-mapper in your pom.xml